# Can dask dashboard be used on SageMaker (Labs 1.2.*)?

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

I don't have browser access to the lab environment, and the available dask extension for lab didn't work for me so far.
I want to be able to see the progress and performance data for my dask projects, no luck for now.

compute() sometimes take hours (it's ok, there is a lot of data), and I feel blind throught the process.

Do you know if there is anything supported by labs 1.2? No luck with progressbar either.
The instance is on AWS SageMaker, so I cannot access the web dashboard.

Thanks!

Comment: I am unsure of this on sagemaker but there should be options for it. Although I am completely unsure, just to guide you I may suggest you to research on ssh tunneling/reverse ssh tunneling. This would get you to open the dashboard on your local machine after ssh connection is ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to save most of the dashboard information in a file with `performance_report` (see [docs](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/diagnostics-distributed.html)):

```py
from dask.distributed import Client, performance_report
import time

client = Client()

def f(x):
    time.sleep(x)
    return x

with performance_report():
    futures = client.map(f, range(5))
    results = client.gather(futures)
```

Note that this will save the final file only once the computation has stopped (either because it was completed or due to an error/interruption).

If you want something that will save information at specific steps/intervals, the simplest solution would be to split computations into chunks and save the information on each chunk. Note that such hacky-saves will reduce the efficiency of parallelisation, since some of the workers might end up idle during frequent `.gather` or `.compute` operations.

Another option is to periodically dump the contents of `client.get_task_stream()`, which returns a tuple containing dictionaries for each task on the scheduler. This can be done either after completion of each future with [`as_completed`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/futures.html) or with some periodicity (e.g. every `n` seconds within a `while` loop). I can't think of a general solution, but it should be possible.

You might also find the links in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66073423/10693596) useful.

Comment: So no way to look at it on real time? It's to cancel if I see something wrong and not if I *feel* that it's taking too long. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of a good way. I updated the answer with another solution, but it's only a suggestion, so you would need to find an appropriate way to integrate this in your code.